# align Modal on the right side in Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4. I want that the modal is aligned right (see picture what I mean):

[image: how I want]

This is my code so far. I got it from the Bootstrap documentation:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalScrollable" id="btn1">mehr Erfahren</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalScrollable" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalScrollableTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle">Winkelstufe</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Schliessen</button>         
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I would appreciate your help on how to do it.

Answer (score 16):

I searched a lot and didn't find a nice answer, so I had to make it from scratch. Easier than I thought:

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
<style>
.modal-dialog {
    position: fixed;
    margin: auto;
    width: 320px;
    height: 100%;
    right: 0px;
}
.modal-content {
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
<div class="container demo">
  <div class="text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-demo" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2"> Right Sidebar Modal </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          Right Sidebar </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: that's nice... but is it possible to transition from the right side?

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML:

```
  <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal right fade" id="myModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel2">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel2">Right Sidebar</h4>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Text</p>
                    </div>

                </div><!-- modal-content -->
            </div><!-- modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- modal -->
```

Sample: https://codepen.io/bootpen/pen/jbbaRa

Comment: somehow this doesn't work. Maybe its not Bootstrap 4?

Comment: Note: This is for BS3 not 4.

Answer (score 0):

**if you what use Bootstrap 4 for grid**

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
   // <!--this for image model-->
        <div class="col-md-7">

        </div>

    <!--this for right model-->
        <div class="col-md-4">

    // your code here //


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't want the content. I just want the the modal is aligned on the right side like the picture

Comment: this is the method for assign a dive with bootstrap you can use your code like

Comment: are you add bootstrap CDN ` <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">`